# using $_GET without using '?'

Tags: php, html

I want to create a link which is catched by **$_GET** in PHP. Let me explain:

Currently i do this in **HTML**:

```
<a href="?contactus">Contact Us</a>
```

And this is what i do in **php**:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['contactus'])){
        include "contactus.php";
    }
?>
```

In this case the address becomes like this `www.domain.com/?contactus`.

But I want the address like this: `www.domain.com/contactus`

If i change html to `<a href="contactus">Contact Us</a>`
but it doesn't work. Anyone please tell me. Thanks

Comment: you're asking for url rewrite, it should be set by your HTTP server

Comment: Search (Google, StackOverflow etc) for "URL Rewrite". There are a lot of resources on the web where you can learn what you need to write in `.htaccess` to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache mod rewrite simple redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838080/apache-mod-rewrite-simple-redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a .htaccess file to make it work

like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contactus\/?/?$ index.php?contactus
</IfModule>
```

and index.php like this

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['contactus'])){
        include "contactus.php";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use domain.com/contactus and parse the URL

```
$url = "http://domain.com/contactus";
$url = parse_url($url);
$path = $url['path']; // contactus
echo $path;  // contactus
```

You can then use it

```
 if ($path == "contactus"){
       include "contactus.php";
    }
```

You will still need URL rewrite, try adding or editing your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^contactus/?$    contactus-page.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "contactus"
```

Comment: It still needs URL rewriting. Otherwise the server doesn't know how to handle the URL and returns `404 Not Found` (i.e. the code you suggests does not have any chance to run).

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to do like this
at page where u set anchor tag do following 
$url="contact.php?page"='contactus'; 
give  href="$url" .

And other side you can use `$urlget = $_GET['page'];`

plz note the attribute u used is page so when u try to get in nother page u need to use `$_GET['page']` and you can see url when you click on contact us page in your address bar there is also contact.php?page='contactus' showing